# I can't install phalcon php in macbook air m1 with monterey.. why?

Tags: php, phalcon, apple-m1

I try to install Phalcon in a mac os m1 with monterey, but say this, anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue open here where someone else appears to be encountering the same problem:

https://github.com/phalcon/homebrew-tap/issues/25.

The Expected you're getting is the sha256 of php-psr-1.0.0.tar.gz:

```
f85be1d1434368abd16e06b81e394487f81b5e2706220f01c85558ba486ee3e7
```

While the Actual you're getting is the sha256 of php-psr-0.7.0.tar.gz

```
648aac07414f8c6e5c80728cf91fa8174bbd18dd41ae1a90168b510a507cf805
```

This is correct on v4.1.0:
https://github.com/phalcon/homebrew-tap/blob/bfa3fd5226777b13bae500f125261d0cd2de936b/Formula/psr%4074.rb#L7,L8

But wrong on master where it's giving you the older psr with a hash for the newer psr, and thus mismatched:
https://github.com/phalcon/homebrew-tap/blob/d5225fb160c46371efdf70d5efe922ab77ceedaf/Formula/psr@74.rb

The README on the phalcon/homebrew-tap says Phalcon 4.1.0 requires php-psr 1.0.0 but the psr@74.rb file has a hash mismatch which would affect php 7.4. This needs to be fixed on master.

I sent in a PR for this:
https://github.com/phalcon/homebrew-tap/pull/26